# First lesson android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-intent

When i start to the aplication in a android device the application crashes after clicking the inly button, that mean that the intent to bring the next activity doesn't work but i don't know where is my error, i'm sure that i misspelled something but where?

```
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154): Process: com.example.myfirstapp, PID:     18154
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     start activity     ComponentInfo{com.example.myfirstapp/com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity}:     java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{41ad8eb0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2215)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2265)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:145)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1206)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5081)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:781)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{41ad8eb0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:930)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:570)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1171)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:5241)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2178)
06-06 21:00:13.692: E/AndroidRuntime(18154):    ... 11 more
06-06 21:00:16.125: I/Process(18154): Sending signal. PID: 18154 SIG: 9
```

And here is the MainActivity
i think here is the error but i don't know where:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.os.Build;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.myfirstapp.MESSAGE";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public void sendMessage (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);
    String message = editText.getText().toString();
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);
    startActivity(intent);
}

/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        return rootView;
    }
}

}
```

And the manifest if there is something that is usefull:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.myfirstapp"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: The problem is in your `DisplayMessageActivity` but you haven't posted code for that. Edit your question and show the code. Also show the XML layout files.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line and check if it works.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

with

```
setContentView(com.example.myfirstapp.R.layout.activity_main);
```

Because there is R.java in android package and if you have imported that accidentally it will create error.

Check if this is the cause, if not then we can diagnose further.

Edit: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f05003c (com.example.myfirstapp:id/container) for fragment PlaceholderFragment{41ad8eb0 #0 id=0x7f05003c}`

This line indicating problem in PlaceholderFragment. So the problem can be in this code

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                    .commit();
        }
```

Here you are trying to add `PlaceholderFragment` to `R.id.container`.

Comment: The app keeps crashing, i think the error is with this line:

Comment: EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_message);

Comment: Then it should have given edit_message can not be resolve error, which I cannot see.

Comment: @Raj: Read the comment I posted on the OP's question. Look at the third line of logcat - the problem is in the `DisplayMessageActivity` and not in the `MainActivity`. You're guessing at answers caused by code the OP hasn't shown us. Until he posts the `DisplayMessageActiviy` and the layout files it's impossible to answer.

Comment: @Raj Well you are also right with your edit regarding the container but it as I said it is related to other code the OP hasn't shown us. Until we see that then nobody can give an accurate answer to what he needs to fix.